# Why is the COVID-19 vaccine called "Спутник V", not "Спутник В"?

Tags: правописание

The [COVID-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severe_acute_respiratory_syndrome_coronavirus_2) vaccine developed by  the Gamaleya Research Institute of Epidemiology and Microbiology is called "Спутник V". Per [the English-language Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputnik_V_COVID-19_vaccine), the "V" is the letter "V", not the Roman numeral five. Apparently, even the original cyrillic spelling is ["Спутник V"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_V), although "V" is not a letter of the [cyrillic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language#Alphabet). I would rather have expected "Спутник В" (capital "в" for "вакцина").

Why was a non-cyrillic letter used even in the original cyrillic name of the vaccine? Was this exclusively driven by marketing, for fear of the rest of the world mistaking a "в" for a (roman) "B"?

Is there a general rule in Russian about using Cyrillic or Latin letters for one letter brand or class names?

Comment: This is the name of the brand, you are basically asking why it was branded that way and not another - it's not a question about Russian language though and won't help other Russian language learners. That said, unfortunately I had to close this question as off-topic. Don't get me wrong, it's a valid question - it's just that it doesn't fit.

Comment: @shabunc: OK, thank you for your explanation - much nicer than just seeing one's question closed :)

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question, but I know the Russian terms 'гепатит A' (hepatitis A), 'гепатит B' (not 'гепатит Б'), 'гепатит C' .   I just read an article about 'Sputnik V' in the Russian Wikipedia. This article uses the terms 'S-белок' (S-protein) and 'N-белок'. For the Russian medical terminology, I think, is a common practice: a combination of a Russian word in Cyrillic and a Latin letter.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! It looks like you are assuming that Russian brand and class names should only be using Cyrillic. I've put this assumption into a question on your behalf, if that's ok, which makes the question on topic.

Comment: C.f "витамин C" for "vitamin C".

Comment: @Elena: your comment is already very enlightening. Would you be interested in expanding it to an answer? I'll happily upvote it, and if anyone has anything better, they can always post it.

Comment: According to this article cited in the Russian version of the Wikipedia article a spokesman for the manufacturer stated on Twitter that the V is victory over COVID-19: https://tass.ru/obschestvo/10348709

Comment: Because other language letters or full names sound better as if the origin of the product is foreign, not local, meaning it is better as almost all foreign in compare to local products. 200 years ago French words were popular as it was #1 language, later english took its place.

Comment: @Александр Волков So, you decided to explain to us why in Russian physics textbooks the letters F and 'm' are used to denote force and mass. This is done for marketing reasons, so that force and mass will make a good impression on the students. And although we do not understand what makes doctors around the world write their prescriptions in Latin, but about Russian doctors everything is clear. As you have just kindly explained to us, the Russians do this out of respect for the fashion for English letters. In the 18th century, they wrote in Latin because of the fashion for letters from France

Answer (score 1):

This "V" means "Victory".

"The letter "V", which is contained in the name of the Sputnik V coronavirus vaccine, means victory. This was announced on Thursday by the сhief of the Russian Direct Investment Fund Kirill Dmitriev in the account of this medication manufacturers on Twitter. ... "
https://tass.ru/obschestvo/10348709

Comment: this is something that Kirill Dmitriev told on a conference and actually can be anecdotal - he is not the creator of vaccine and to my knowledge (pretty limited though) had nothing to do with this branding.

Answer (score -4):

May be it symbolizes victory. In Russian "s Putinim" means "with Putin", so the whole name may mean "victory with Putin". Also, notice that Putin has the two other his initials V.V. So, it can be read "s Putinim V." (with Putin V.)

Comment: That is interesting. Do you have any information to back this up? Per the English-language Wikipedia, the "V" is indeed the letter "V", not the numeral for "five", and the source given is an English-language YouTube video purportedly created by the company that created the vaccine. Also see [David42's comment](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/23325/why-is-the-covid-19-vaccine-called-%d0%a1%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-v-not-%d0%a1%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%92/23364#comment45827_23325).

Comment: @StephanKolassa Also, notice that Putin has the two other his initials V.V. So, it can be read "s Putinim V." (with Putin V.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa: I believe looking at the calendar would back it up the best.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. Which calendar? Are you referring to edit histories of the Wikipedia page, or the timestamp of the YouTube video?

Comment: @StephanKolassa: this post is either an April fools' day joke or a genuine crazy nonsense. I'm inclined to believe the former.

Comment: @Quassnoi what is non-sciential here?

Comment: @Anixx: I don't really know where to start. So, just to clarify, it's not a joke, is it?

Comment: @Quassnoi no, this is not a joke.

Comment: @Anixx I'm not sure what happened with you recently but can not help but notice that your recent answers are quite often down-voted for a reason.

Comment: @shabunc dont u think it could be named after Putin V?

Comment: While my first reaction also was to downvote this, on the afterthought - Wikipedia has a link for an explanation why it is letter V rather than Roman numeral V; the link leads to a Youtube link with a clear specimen of a махровая Kremlin propaganda which opens with  "The world is craving for VICTORY OVER COVID-19". Which, I think, indeed indicates that it might be designed to work on the subconscious level to link Victory with Vladimir and Sputnik with Putin or whatever

Comment: (And let me also mention the obvious - Vladimir can be translated as "rule the world")